# PowerShell find files by extension on multiple servers and export

Tags: powershell, file

I wrote a script to find the particular file on windows servers based on Disks and exporting that list to .txt file for each server and drive.

I want to run the script for multiple servers and export all the list details in one csv or excel file with server name and the file location path as output.

```
#Clearing the Host file
Clear-Host

#Get all the list of Servers
$Machines = get-content "C:\Scripts\Servers.txt"

#Get all the list of Disks to search
$Disks = get-content "C:\Scripts\Disks.txt"

#Lopping through specified servers
foreach ($Machine in $Machines) 
{
#Lopping through each Disks
    foreach ($Disk in $Disks) 
    {
        if (Test-Path \\$Machine\$Disk$) 
        {
            Write-Host Checking $Machine Disk $Disk -BackgroundColor DarkRed
            Get-ChildItem -Path \\$Machine\$Disk$\ -Filter log4j.jar -Recurse -Name -Force | Out-File "C:\Scripts\Output\$Machine $Disk.txt"
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: You forgot to ask a question... Is the script not working? Partly working? Does it throw errors when you run it? Is the output file not containing the expected output?

Comment: My script is working as expected but it is giving the out for each server with drive name as a separated file and the output contains only the path, but i need to get the output in one single csv file for all the servers with the entire file location path as well

Answer (score 1):

Don't send output from the script until you have the information you need.

Using a custom object will allow you to store the values you want

```
#Clear Host
Clear-Host

#Get all the list of Servers
$Machines = get-content "C:\Scripts\Servers.txt"

#Get all the list of Disks to search
$Disks = @('D','G')

# Looping through specified servers
foreach ($Machine in $Machines) {
#Looping through each Disks
    $FileResults  = $Disks | ForEach-Object {
        If (Test-Path \\$Machine\$_$) {
            Write-Host Checking $Machine Disk $_ -BackgroundColor DarkRed
            $DiskResults = Get-ChildItem -Path \\$Machine\$_$\ -Filter log4j.jar -Name -Recurse -Force
        #
        # Send the results of each disk to custom object, to be stored in $FileResults
        #
            [pscustomobject]@{Disk=$_;Files=$DiskResults}
        }
    }
    If (-not $FileResults) {
        $FileResults = 'None found'
    }
    #
    # Send the results of each completed server
    #
    [pscustomobject]@{ComputerName=$Machine;Found=$FileResults}
    #
}
```

Comment: how can i export the results to the .csv file or xlsx file

Comment: There's an Export-Csv commandlet.....